# No boot menu for Windows XP or Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, boot

I have just installed Windows XP alongside Windows 7.

Now I can't boot Windows 7 because it automatically boots Windows XP without displaying a boot menu.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Reference [Installing XP as a second OS](https://neosmart.net/wiki/easybcd/dual-boot/windows-xp/installing-second/)

> **Setting up the Dual-Boot**
>
> Once Windows XP setup has finished, it’ll automatically boot you into
> the newly installed copy of Windows XP – note that you will not be
> able to boot into Vista/7 at this point, nor will you see a boot menu
> option for it. This is because Windows XP has installed its own
> bootloader on top of the Windows Vista bootloader, and it does not
> recognize newer versions of Windows.
>
> - Once in Windows XP, download and install the [Microsoft .NET 2.0 Framework SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16614).
> - Download and install the [latest version of EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/).
> - Once in EasyBCD, go to the “Bootloader Setup” page, and select “Install the Windows Vista/7 bootloader to the MBR” then “Write MBR”
>   to get the EasyBCD bootloader back.
>
> [image]
>
> - Once that’s done, head on to the “Add New Entry” page and select “Windows NT/2k/XP/2003″ from the drop-down list, give it a name, then
>   press “Add Entry” to finish. Leave the checkbox for automatic
>   configuration checked, and do not manually change the drive in EasyBCD
>   thereafter. The settings EasyBCD chooses may look wrong, but it’s
>   complicated.
>
> [image]
>
> - Now reboot.
>
> You won’t be able to select the drive that your Windows XP entry
> points to. This is because EasyBCD will automatically search for
> NTLDR, the Windows XP bootloader, and pick the right drive for you.
> For more information, read the main Windows XP page. Don’t try
> changing this yourself, your system will not boot if you do!

Answer (score 0):

As you said, by default you are logged into Windows XP.

After you have logged into Windows XP, in order to choose the default operating system, you need to follow these steps below:

Click on **Start**/**Windows** symbol ⇒ Right click **My Computer** and go to **Properties**:

[image: Right click My Computer and go to Properties]

Now you can see **System Properties** window, select the **Advanced** tab, Go to the **Startup and Recovery** option and click the **Settings** button:

[image: Go to Startup and Recovery option: Settings]

As per your wish choose the default OS. Once you have chosen your OS then click on “OK”. Restart your machine.

[image: Choose your default OS then click on OK]

Note: If you need to increase the time that operating system list is displayed, you can also do so here. After all of your changes, click on “OK” and restart your machine.

Answer (score 0):

Use your win7/vista CD at boot and select repair and try select startup repair at recovery options..
If it doesnt work.. Try

with Win 7 Cd at bootup...
in system recovry options..select command prompt.type command

bootrec /FixMbr.

Then try restartng system without CD